# How can I count how many cells in an excel spreadsheet have a non-specific time range in them?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Background: Im a manager at a retail business and am trying to figure out what times/days people born in a certain year come into our shop on average. To do this, I have a list of all members of that age and then a list of all the times all people come in. Currently, I am going through all of the customer's transactions manually and keeping a tally of what time they have visited the shop. This is extremely tedious and time consuming.

How I think I can solve this quicker, if I knew how:
I'd like to be able to find all cells that are, for example, time stamped from 12:00:00 PM to 12:59:59 PM. This would then give me a total count of all times that all customers on this list visited the shop. How might I go about this? I'd really prefer to use the "find all" tool to do this. I thought I may be able to put in something like 12:xx:xx PM but that didn't work.

Hoping I've explained this clearly enough to get an answer, or a push in the right direction.

Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by non-specific time,,, any random period or time interval ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Pivot table.

Put the Time in both the Rows and Values.

Make sure it is set to count of time:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking at doing is a little bit more complicated than using a formula with just a simple `COUNTIFS()` or `SUMPRODUCT()`. It requires a two-dimensional array formula.

I have created an example worksheet that will hopefully get you started.

Setup a worksheet like the following:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Array-enter (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) the following formula in `I3` and then copy-paste/fill down:

```dart
{=SUM(($C$3:$C$15>=G3)*($C$3:$C$15<=H3)*($D$3:$D$15=TRANSPOSE(OFFSET($K$3:$K$15,,MATCH(F3,$K$2:$M$2,0)-1))))}
```

---

The prettified version of the formula is as follows:

```dart
{=
SUM(
   ($C$3:$C$15>=G3)
  *($C$3:$C$15<=H3)
  *($D$3:$D$15=TRANSPOSE(OFFSET($K$3:$K$15,,MATCH(F3,$K$2:$M$2,0)-1)))
)}
```

**Explanation:**

The first two sub-expressions inside the `SUM()` create one-dimensional column arrays to filter for the required time interval.

The third sub-expression creates a two-dimensional array consisting of a column for each of the cells of the appropriate column of the Birth Year table, thus filtering for only those transactions matching the people born in that year.

The `OFFSET($K$3:$K$15,,MATCH(F3,$K$2:$M$2,0)-1)` selects the appropriate Birth Year column depending on the value in `F3`, e.g. the value `1991` would select `$L$3:$L$15`. The `TRANSPOSE()` is required to convert the column array to a row array so that the multiplication results in a 2-D array. 
**Notes:**

- The prettified formula actually works if entered.

Answer (score -1):

*Suppose you want to count number of customers visited between a time interval then your formula should any of the followings:*

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A20,">="&C2,A2:A20,"<="&D2)

=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A20>=C2) * (A2:A20<=D2))
```

If the data range has **Date Time stamp** then your formula should be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ROUND(MOD(A2:A20,1),10)>=C2) * (ROUND(MOD(A2:A20,1),10)<=D2))
```

**N.B.** Where C2 has 08:30 & D2 has 12:00.